# How to set value in select option dynamically in angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, materialize

I have a select option as below

```
<div class="input-field col width">
  <select name="GENDER" class="genderSelect" ng-model="view.activeResource.ValueType" ngModel>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <label>Gender</label>
</div>
```

Now what i did is saved the data when i wanted to save. My issue which i am facing is set the same saved value to this select option. 
I am able to get my value but just setting the same value is not working for me. If trying to set the value using jquery then when i click on save button again data going as null value.

Not sure what is the right way to set value using angular.

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery, while using Angular? Probably you should read about data binding: [link](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#data-binding)

Comment: your are using AngularJs right? "ng-model" is form AngularJs times. In Angular you want to use `[ngModel]="view.activeResource...."`
Please add the JavaScript code of your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [selected] attribute in every option to compare their values to the one you saved.

`<option value="male" [selected]="savedGenderExample === 'male'">Male</option>`